# Why objects look like this?

Tags: rendering, objects

I'm having this problem where objects look transparent but I don't know why. in the shader editor, they look like this.
[image]

And when I render it looks like an alpha mask? I don't know.
[image]

I don't know what to do, I've already reinstalled Blender.

Comment: This is a gpu issue with AMD at the moment.  Previous driver version may fix it.